# Flutter: How To Use If Statements In Decoration

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a custom navbar so i cant use `currentIndex` as i am using a `SizedBox`. So i am trying to pass a variable `page` to each widget that uses the navbar so that i can put a condition that decides what styling will be used. but i am getting errors when trying to put an if statement inside a widget is there any way to work around this? or is there a better way to do this?

error 1: Error: Place positional arguments before named arguments.
Try moving the positional argument before the named arguments, or add a name to the argument. if (page == 0)

error 2: Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'if'.
Try inserting an identifier before 'if'.

```
Container(
  child: Text(
    'Habits',
     style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 24.0,
       if (page == 0){
         color: Colors.black,
       } else {
         color: Colors.white,
       }
     ),
   ),

   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

   decoration: BoxDecoration(

     if (page == 0){
       color: Colors.white,
     } else {
       color: Color(0XFF101010),
     }

     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0))

   ),
        
),
```

question 2: I am using a custom navbar class for each of my pages so i have a common class between them but i need to know which page is active so i am using a variable called `page` which acts as an index for each of my pages. How can i pass this as an argument in the widget

code:

```
    /* edited



    class HabitsPage extends StatefulWidget {

        final int page = 0;

        const HabitsPage({
          Key Key,
          this.page,

        }) : super(Key: Key);


  @override
  _HabitsPageState createState() => _HabitsPageState();
}


    */

class _HabitsPageState extends State<HabitsPage> {

  int page = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,


      appBar: MyAppbar(


      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyNavBar(
        //pass integer in

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

navbar

```
   child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0XFF101010),
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 1.0,
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
        Container(
          child: Text(
            'Habits',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,

              color: page == 0 ? Colors.black : Colors.white,


            ),
          ),

          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: page == 0 ? Colors.white : Color(0XFF101010),






            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0))

            ),


            /*decoration: BoxDecoration(

            color: Color(0XFF101010),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0))

            ),*/

          ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **`ternary`** operator.

#### Example

```
color: page == 0 ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
```

#### Try this

```
Container(
  child: Text(
    'Habits',
     style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 24.0,
       color: page == 0 ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
     ),
   ),
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: age == 0 ? Colors.white : Color(0XFF101010),
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0))
   ),    
),
```

Comment: Thank you, do you also know how to pass an integer in to a widget? i will update the question with the code to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

For question number 2.

You pass the `page` parameter to the Widget constructor and then access it with `widget.page` inside the state.

Example:

```
class HabitsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int page;

  const HabitsPage({
    Key key,
    this.page,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _HabitsPageState createState() => _HabitsPageState();
}

class _HabitsPageState extends State<HabitsPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(widget.page);
    
    return Scaffold(

      
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,


      appBar: MyAppbar(


      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyNavBar(
        //pass integer in

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting these errors Error: 'page' is a final instance variable that was initialized at the declaration.
    this.page,